# Vb6 / Crystal reports 8.5: how to use a subreport within one main report? How to link data?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

could you please help me on putting a subreport within a main designed report and link data between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the subreport you simply choose Subreport from the Insert menu and go through the steps of creating the new subreport or pointing to an existing report to be used for the subreport.

If you choose to do a new report you give it a name and choose Report Wizard to create the subreport. After you've chosen your connection you simply create a report as you would normally with the wizard. You can set up a link in the report selection section of the wizard, but the easiest way is to right click on the new subreport that you added to your main report and choose Change Subreport Links. Here you can specify which field from the main report will link to a field in the subreport. The Subreport Links screen is pretty self-explanatory so give that a try and you should be able to figure it out pretty quick. Hope this helps.